# "Replay" tcpdump file

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, pcap, tcpdump

I am writing a program for analyzing certain type of packets. I got the dump file containing test packets in tcpdump format. is there any way to send this dump into one of the interfaces? I thought tcpdump would be able to do this on its own (unfortunately it isn't). Only thing I managed to do is to look at packets via wireshark (which obviously isn't the way to go).

I could use libpcap function `pcap_open_offline()`, unfortunately I use `pcap_loop()` which doesn't seem to work with `pcap_open_offline()` and rewriting code to `pcap_next()` would be very painful. Is there any program that could send packets to the interface?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try to take a look to [tcpreplay](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcpreplay) that is done to :

> Replay network traffic stored in pcap files

Comment: thank you, I wasn't aware of this program and didn't find it by searching. It helped me solve the bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of libpcap provide a [`pcap_inject()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcap_inject/) function that can be used to write packets back out.

You can see [someone's testing program to use `pcap_inject()` over on UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=525762).